# django login_required decorator, always redirect to login page, even after logging in

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

code in views.py

```
def custom_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)            
            return redirect('main')
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        user = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': user})

@login_required
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatters =[url(r'^$', views.custom_login, name='login'),
url(r'^main', views.main, name='main')]
```

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',]

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main'
```

If I don't put login_required decorator on main, I am able to redirect to main. but if I use login_required decorator, I am getting redirected back to login page after login with URL `http://localhost:9000/sample_app/?next=/sample_app/main`
I am using python3 with django

**UPDATE**
I had made a silly mistake, I had these settings enabled in my setting. 
`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

Which was rejecting the normal http request. But it works using SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had made a silly mistake, I had these settings enabled in my setting.

`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

Which was rejecting the normal http request. Disabling it works in http. But it works using SSL

Answer (score 0):

Possible errors.
=>Is your user active? If not try activating the account.

=>Try using email to authenticate e.g.

```
user2=None

   try:
        user2=User.objects.get(username=username) # filter.first should do same
    except:
        pass
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is None and user2 is not None:
        user = authenticate(username=user2.email,password=password)
```

=> Try to handle the "next" argument

Hope this helps.

Comment: in tables, `is_active` field is set to `1`

Comment: i will suppress next argument with `@login_required(redirect_field_name=None`). It wont show next parameter after redirecting

Answer (score 0):

**I think your user in not active that you are using in authenticate method.**

Authenticate method check user is active or not. If user not active then it will return None and If user active then will return User instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line in your view,

```
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

To,

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: `user is not None` is going true,it's just login_reuired decorator is redirecting it back to login

Comment: Your recommended change  for `authenticate` function had no effect

Comment: When you post the data using submit button in your template, what is showing in the terminal, I mean where the server runs?? Could you show that please??

Comment: Are you using any namespaces for your URLs?? Could you show the project urls.py

Comment: urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
         url(r'^sample_app/', include('sample_app.urls')),]

Comment: I had one simple mistake,  I have updated the question with answer

Comment: 1 for working it out though...!! Then, it was not the problem of login_required decorator..

Comment: yes, I was pulling my hair out, why this normal thing is not working. But at least found, a common mistake, which could happen with anyone